# Filter YouTube to avoid spoilers

Tags: youtube

I do not know whether this is the right StackExchange site, but I would like to ask whether I can tell YouTube somehow (without installing add-ons to my browser) to top showing me anything related to Game of Thrones. I am not currently planning to watch this year's season and when I get to watch it, I would like to do so without knowing everything that is going to happen. The YouTubers are so stupid (sorry for that word, but it really bothers me) that they are putting images and titles to their videos which spoil the plot just by accidentally looking at the reference.

Unfortunately, going anonymous does not work here either; tried that and failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can do is tell YouTube with all means available to you that you aren't interested in GoT content, ie by not watching any GoT-related stuff and immediately marking whatever you do see as not relevant (3-dot-menu next to the title, usually).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I could not find a way to mark a video as unwanted.